# Add information to datagridview (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

Ok I change my question...

I have two split-arrays and two columns (first name and last name).  How can I add my two split-arrays to my datagridview?

My code does not work, because all last name entries are at first name.

```
For k = 0 To UBound(array1)
    datagradview.Rows.Add(array1(k))

    For i = 0 To UBound(array2)
        datagradview.Rows.Add(array2(i))
    Next (i)
Next (k)
```

Comment: you can edit your questions instead of asking a new one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411090/add-information-to-datagridview-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different approach other than UBound firstly, try to use "Count" or Length where possible so you don't end up with top heavy arrays.

If you have two one-dimensional arrays (which are of the same length) then define the columns in a new DataTable as they should be displayed in your DGV and then use your DGV.DataSource = your new DataTable:

```
 Dim resultsDT as New DataTable
 resultsDT.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(System.String))
 resultsDT.Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(System.String))

  Dim k as Int16
  For k = 0 to array1.Length - 1
  resultsDT.Rows.Add(array1(k), array2(k))
  Next k

  DataGridView_Results.DataSource = resultsDT
```

I hope this helps